# JQuery Mobile with dynamic collapsible content blocks (via Spry) not expanding

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, jquery-mobile, spry

I just don't get it! This is obviously a FAQ, but I just can't find a clear enough example for a dummy like me.

**Problem**
I have built a JQM page which is populated based on data loaded using Spry. The page layout works fine, but the collapsible content blocks are drawn but won't expand when clicked.

The code is currently:

```
    <div spry:when="'{Source}' == 'gp'">
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3>{LastName}</h3>
        <p>{PatientFullName}: <i>{Headline}</i><br/>DOB: {DOB}, GP: {GP}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The variables included in {} are automatically populated via the Spry load. (And this bit works). I'd also like to keep with Spry as it offers the filtering and sorting options I need on the XML I get passed.

On the JQM site at http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html (and within this site) ther is lots of talk about using a button linked to page() to allow JQM to apply it's markup to these new elements. I don't want a button, I want to have this automatically triggered once the data load has completed.

I have been working on this for 24 hours and Javascript/JQuery just aren't my thing, so I wondered if someone could help me with the error of my ways. I just need the idiots guide on how to make the call.

Thanks very much in advance.
Pete.

Answer (score 0):

Are you binding to the pageinit in order to load your Spry dataset? If so, can you try changing to pagecreate? Does that produce different results?

Can you paste some of your JavaScript?